# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing in Python 3 while import csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and trying to read a csv file in the dataframe.

I am getting the following error:-

[image]

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the previous posts to rectify it however, I am unable to.Can you please help.

Comment: Please post code that we can cut & paste to reproduce the error.  We generally don't accept either a link or an image.

Answer (score 0):

Your `try:` block is incomplete.  You must have a result block of some sort, usually an `except:` block.

Comment: Okay. There was another line of code. When I tried using all of it, I am getting a different error.

Comment: I am getting a ParseError: Error Tokenizing data

Comment: You will not get a solution by replacing one error with another error. Please post the complete try-except block.